# Floated div unexpectedly clearing previous float

Tags: css

I'm having a (probably stupid) problem with floating div.  I have each div sized at one or two-thirds of screen width (on wide enough displays).

Where I have a short 67% div floated left then a tall 33% div floated right then a short 67% div floated left, I'd expect the third div lined up immediately underneath the first with the second continuing down to its right, as at http://jsfiddle.net/BluefireAdz/bqdpfv8w/

```
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 67%; background-color: #aaaa00; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 67%; background-color: #aa0000; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: right; width: 33%; background-color: #00aa00; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 67%; background-color: #0000aa; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
```

However, something (probably in my CSS) is pushing it down so that it only starts at the bottom of the second div, as at http://jsfiddle.net/BluefireAdz/9bho8s5b/ (code made as clean as I can easily make it and still having the problem).

```
<div class="w67" style="background-color: #aaaa00; ">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="w67" style="background-color: #aa0000; ">
    <div class="b3_vplayer">
        <div class="embed-container">
            <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/06olHmcJjS0?autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;theme=light" style="border: 0; "></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w33" style="background-color: #00aa00; ">
    <img src="http://www.killersites.com0killerSites/resources/dot_clear.gif" alt="Image 1" style="width: 286px; height: 300px; margin: 1em 0 0 0" />
    <img src="http://www.killersites.com/killerSites/resources/dot_clear.gif" alt="Image 2" style="width: 286px; height: 300px; margin: 1em 0 0 0" />
</div>
<div class="w67" style="background-color: #0000aa; ">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Have tried in Edge, IE and Firefox and get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

See my updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bho8s5b/1/
Basically I just brought the floated right div before the other divs.

```
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: right; width: 33%; background-color: #00aa00; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 67%; background-color: #aaaa00; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 67%; background-color: #aa0000; color: #ffffff; ">
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>

<div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 67%; background-color: #0000aa; color: #ffffff;">
    &nbsp;<br />
</div>
```

Comment: I would, but I'm trying to keep the content in order (on narrower screens they're all 100% width) - I can't see what's making it behave differently to the simpler example fiddle I quoted

Answer (score 1):

Update your code in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9bho8s5b/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float:left; width: 67%;">
    <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 100%; background-color: #aaaa00; color: #ffffff; ">
        &nbsp;<br />
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; float: left; width: 100%; background-color: #aa0000; color: #ffffff; ">
        &nbsp;<br />
    </div>    
</div>
```

You can wrap your first two div's in another div which is of 67% width and the internal divs which take full width.

Answer (score 0):

You can change up your HTML so that the div that is set to `float:right` appears first, followed by the 3 `float:left`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bho8s5b/3/).

Comment: I would, but I'm trying to keep the content in order (on narrower screens they're all 100% width) - I can't see what's making it behave differently to the simpler example fiddle I quoted

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - I wasn't actually floating the w33 div to the right! Have added `float: right` to the inline style and now it all floats as hoped for!